# spring boot + Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile in Java 17 + buid through Docker

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dockerfile, java-17

I use a project with Spring booot 2.7.0 and Java 17 (OpenJdk). I try to build the project When I use to build with Dockerfile.

- pom.xml

```xml
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.counter</groupId>
    <artifactId>counter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>counter</name>
    <description>counter</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>counter</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I run a command

```
docker image build . -t counter:1.0.0
```

I have an error:

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project counter-service: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]

Maybe Someone have met that error or Maybe Someone have ideas to correct that problem.

Comment: Obviously the docker image does not correctly contain JDK17... ?

Comment: a good reference to take a note of https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk

Answer (score 0):

I have updated image for base of Docker-container.

**openjdk:17-alpine3.14**

```yaml
FROM openjdk:17-alpine3.14
ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN ./mvnw clean package -DskipTests
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","target/counter.jar"]
```